# Custom Font Color for Completed Items in List

Tags: designer-workflow, filter, custom-view, indicator

A part of my workflow writes the items over to another list where users can see their outstanding invoices that need approving. However, the workflow logic goes, the filter only proves false and the item disappears at the end of the entire workflow.

I have the user list filtered based on if the choice column is set to "Open" and if my user profile is set as one of the 3 reviewers. Otherwise, if this condition is not met, the item is not on the list.

I am trying to figure out some way that the item will only stay on the list when it is assigned to the current reviewer. I attempted to do this by adding additional choice columns and then changing the status of that column after each user is assigned, and then closing/updating once the approval is made. However... when I go to modify the list and setup filters, there is no grouping so it only judges by what it reads.

For example:

[Item Status] is equal to Open
and
[Reviewer 1] is equal to [Me]
OR
[Item Status 2] is equal to Open
and
[Reviewer 2] is equal to [Me]
OR
[Item Status 3] is equal to Open
and
[Reviewer 3] is equal to [Me]

If the filter was just looking for the Item Status to be open and the reviewer to be me, then the item would work fine, but when it sees other "ands" in the statements, it considers it to be false since it doesn't meet the conditions.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or maybe ideas on shading the line item a different color or using an indicator once the item has been approved?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to apply a filter to your list to show/hide specific items or do you want to highlight specific items? This was not clear from your question.

Comment: I already have a filter on the list to show when User 1, 2 or 3 equals [Me] and if the [Status]="Open". What I am needing is some way that the individual user can see that he/she has completed their part, other wise it remains on their list. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's difficult to mix and/or into logic without using (), I'd hack at this by adding a hidden field to your list to simplify the logic. I don't think I have the syntax correct, but it's close.

Add a field 'ThisIsOpen', calculated field, that returns as Yes/No, that tests the 3 status fields.

```
=OR([Item Status]="Open",[Item Status 2]="Open", [Item Status 2] ="Open")
```

Then your filter could be simplified to

```
[Reviewer 1] is equal to [Me] OR
[Reviewer 2] is equal to [Me] OR
[Reviewer 3] is equal to [Me]
AND
[ThisIsOpen] is true
```

That will go through all the ORs testing for yourself, then ANDing in the fact that it has to be open. Conditionals are tested - first 2 are evaluated, then the next one added to that, then the next one.... that's why the AND has to be last.